# How to put own HTML into Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I installed a Wordpress theme, but I would need to put there my own HTML code.
So, I would suppose I'll go into: `wp-content/themes/theme_name/header.php` and on the needed place I inserted needed HTML code.

I did it, but it didn't affect the website - the newly put HTML elements are not seen in the website.
Do I disregard anything? Or is needed to set up something in the WP administration?
Or problem with cache?

Sorry, maybe a stupid queston, I am just playing with WP for the first time.

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the currently active theme?

Comment: Important note: when I go into the THEMES section in administration and I click on the CUSTOMIZE button for the theme, I see there a preview of this theme and there is my code displayed. So maybe problem with cache?

Comment: i don't think wordpress caches html fragments somehow ? It can cache css and js only.

Answer (score 1):

The pages of your blog are created from different theme "parts". `header.php` is one of them. it creates the header of the page. Usually, before most HTML is output. `footer.php` is used for the footer of the page. 
If you want your HTML code to go in the homepage only, use index.php (which calls `header.php` and `footer.php`). If you want your code to show in a page, use `page.php`. If you want your code to show when viewing a post, use `single.php`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your different pages if `get_header()` function is called correctly. It is this function that includes `header.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Check also your `"theme_name/inc"` directory. Sometimes the `header.php` or `footer.php` can be placed in the main theme folder **and** in the inc. If that is the situation you need to make sure to be editing the right file (the one in `/inc`).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check in wp-admin which theme is actives in your site suppose there are three theme and twenty eleven is active and you were checking twenty twelve so maybe this reason your new html will not shown in front-end so please check your current theme and work according to that from this location you can check it your current theme go to wp-admin => appearance => themes