# Correct place to store HTML in WordPress theme

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423805/how-to-put-own-html-into-wordpress-theme)

I see about 4 ways to add regular HTML to a WordPress site:

- Use the theme PHP files
- Use the Text Widget
- Use Javascript
- Write a Post / Page and include the HTML there

My content includes a few buttons and descriptions/images of products. My current theme is a single-page website.

For a single-page website, and assuming that I won't need access to a lot of PHP, where should I place the content html?

Comment: [this][1] which one ?

Comment: Sorry about that - the link wasn't preserved from when I started this question on my laptop. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking... But I'm assuming you're asking about how to enter your HTML into a single page theme given that you only have one text editor in WP?

If that's correct, you could try the really amazing advanced custom fields plugin. I'm not sure if you'll need their pro version but you can then add multiple editors, one for each section

Comment: Is it a form or only static content?

Comment: @Nekomajin42 It is mostly static content that I am entering. I am also going to implement a couple of simple forms using a plugin.

Comment: There is a few good custom form plugin for Wordpress. Most of them generates a shortcode for a custom form, which you can insert into the post/page. I reccomend using a page with shortcodes and static content, because it is reuseable, easy to maintain, and you can create more pages in the future, if necessary. It requires the least hacking.

Comment: @Nekomajin42 Thanks for the insight. I want the least hacky way so if it's by doing a plugin i'm game :). I love the fact that there are so many ways to add content but I hate it as well.